# LocalStragety is getting called in passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-local, nuxt.js

I was just checking out the functionality of [passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) and followed this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619) with [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) and was getting started with **passportjs**.I have created LocalStragety called signup which is not getting called on `authenicate()` function.Here's code I have tried starting with `index.js`

```
 app.use(session({
  secret: 'do-different',
  saveUninitialized: false
  }))

 app.use(flash())
 passport.serializeUser(function (people, done) {
  return done(null, people.id)
 })

  passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  return done(null, id)
  })

  app.set('port', port)
  app.use(cookieParser('think different'))


  app.use(bodyParser.json()) // to support JSON-encoded bodies
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
  }))
   app.use(passport.initialize())
   app.use(passport.session())
```

And here's the `route.js` where I create LocalStragety and use authentication.

```
let passport = require('passport')
let LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
let { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router()

passport.use('register', new LocalStrategy({passReqtoCallback: true}, function (request, username, password, done) {
  console.log('request ' + request)
  console.log('username ' + username)
  return done(null, username)
}))

router.post('/register', 
passport.authenticate('register', { failureRedirect: '/home', flashFailure: true }),
 (request, response, next) => {
console.log('request : ' + request.user)
console.log('response : ' + response)
})
```

And nothing is printed on submit action , there are no error , no clue I don't know where I went wrong and Am sure that request to passed to `router.post('/register')`When I tried this lines of code.

```
  router.post('/register', 
 (request, response, next) => {
console.log('user : ' + request.user)
console.log('response : ' + response)
})
```

Somehow am getting this output as I debugged.

```
 user : undefined
 response : [Object object]
```

Am using axios from posting and here's the code.

```
 axios.post('/register', {
    'username': this.username,
    'firstname': this.firstname,
    'lastname': this.lastname,
    'phoneno': this.phoneno,
    'password': this.password,
    'email': this.emailId
  }).
```

Comment: not sure you're missing but I've implemented **passport.js** with **Nuxt.js** and [auth module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module) before. Check this [example](https://github.com/Syffs/auth-module/tree/api-auth/examples)

Comment: I'll check it out @Syffys , thanks for mentioning ...